# Unify :contains query and input[value*=''] within the same query

Tags: jquery, html

I have two different queries I would like to unify them in a single query. One is a query which tracks an HTML element which contains a word as text:

```
var component = ".component";
$(component).find(".search-here:contains('test')");

<tr class="search-here">
  <td>test</td>
</tr>
```

Other one is a query which tracks the inputs of a form and checks the text value of them:

```
var component = "#form";
$(component).find("input[type='text']:input[value*='test']").closest('.search-here');

<div class="search-here">
  <input type="text" value="test, test1, test2">
</div>
```

Both of them, form or any HTMl component have the value I want to track wrapped by a .search-here class

The issue here is I cant track the inputs of a form with :contains because they dont have a text value, they have an attribute called "value"

Having two different queries is a bit messy and tricky, would it be possible to do it in a single generic query without having to modify the form which can query "text" word being a value property or a text value?

Comment: maybe something like `$(component).filter("[type='text'],[value*='test']");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like `$(component).filter("[type='text'],[value*='test'],:contains('test')").closest('.search-here')`

As long as the input has a type = text or a value with test in it, it will return.

**Demo**

```js
var component = ".search-here *";
var s = $(component).filter("[type='text'],[value*='test'],:contains('test')").closest('.search-here');

console.log($(s).length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <div class="search-here">
    <input type="text" value="test, test1, test2">
  </div>
  <div class="search-here">
  <input type="number" value="run"/>
  </div>
</form>

<table>
  <tr class="search-here">
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The problem is the first example I provided is a table, it is not an input, it just have a text wrapped between <td>

Comment: Try look in the demo now.

Comment: Ok it almost works! for the table type it works perfectly, but for the form type it returns all the search-here elements even if they dont have a test like value. Why can this be happening? also what does .search-here * asterisk means?

Comment: The `*` after `.search-here` will look for all children inside the `.search-here` no matter what kind of element it is. also look at my example i have now 2 inputs in it and it only returns the one search-here that has an input with 1 of the required rules

Comment: I tried your example, change second input type number to text and it tracks both of them even if the second one doenst have a test like value, mmm maybe it's because it tracks every input text? I think it will work without [type='text']

Comment: @lapinkoira Im confused, shall it return if a input has both value and type? or just one of those?

Comment: Just all .search-here with inputs which have value*=word and all .search-here which :contains('word'), I think (component).filter("value*='test'],:contains('test')").closest('.search-here'); works for me

Comment: @lapinkoira I hope it helped you get closer to the required result.

Comment: Yes, I am now in the good track to join subqueries with filter, thanks